# How to open graphical files picker in Flutter on Linux?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, filepicker

I have problems with opening graphical files picker on Linux in Flutter, Flutter just cannot do it "from box" on Desktop. I am using Flutter 1.24.0-3.0.pre to get Desktop support in Dart.

So, how to open it on Linux?

(I've created this question after solving it, for sharing answer to you)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [a plugin](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/tree/master/plugins/file_chooser) for this that works on all the desktop platforms, and supports both open and save panels.

Answer (score 0):

I've created class to do it:

```
class FilePicker {
  String pickFile(String extension) {
    bool _noExtension = false;
    String _file = "undefined";

    Process.run('which', ['zenity'], runInShell: true).then((pr) {
      if (pr.exitCode != 0) {
        print("zenity not found.");
        return null;
      }

      print("zenity found.");
    });

    if (extension == "undefined") {
      _noExtension = true;
      print("WARNING: extension not specified.");
    }

    Process.run(
            'zenity',
            [
              '--file-selection',
              !_noExtension ? '--file-filter=' + '*.' + extension + '' : '',
            ],
            runInShell: false)
        .then((pr) {
      if (pr.exitCode != 0) {
        print("user canceled choice.");
        print(pr.stderr.toString());
        print(pr.stdout.toString());
        return null;
      }

      _file = pr.stdout.toString();
      print("File: " + _file);
      return _file;
    });

    return null;
  }

  String pickDirectory() {
    String _dir = "undefined";

    Process.run('which', ['zenity'], runInShell: true).then((pr) {
      if (pr.exitCode != 0) {
        print("zenity not found.");
        return null;
      }

      print("zenity found.");
    });

    Process.run('zenity', ['--file-selection', '--directory'], runInShell: true)
        .then((pr) {
      if (pr.exitCode != 0) {
        print("user canceled choice.");
        print(pr.stderr.toString());
        print(pr.stdout.toString());
        return null;
      }

      _dir = pr.stdout.toString();
      print("Directory: " + _dir);
      return _dir;
    });

    return null;
  }
}
```

Methods:

FilePicker().pickFile("extension");

Pick file with GTK graphical picker, you can to not specify the extension, by typing "undefined" in function arguments

FilePicker().pickDirectory();

Pick directory with GTK graphical picker

Code can be poor, I am newbie in Dart and Flutter :)

Comment: Launching a separate process is going to give a significantly worse user experience than an in-process dialog.